# Datastage Link Name Placement

Tags: datastage

When designing DataStage Sequential and Parallel jobs, I will spend a fair amount of time organizing Stage Link Names so they are easy on the eyes and easily readable like this example: [Organized Stage Link Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXrOP.png)

After Organizing, I will save and compile the job and all the link name positions will still be in the location I placed them. However, when I close and re-open the job, the Stage Link Names are moved and all jumbled up again like this: [Stage Link Names After Re-Open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKfDY.png)

Is there any way to force the link names to stay where I place them? I have been through all the setting panels I can think of with no luck.

1. Name Stage Links
2. Move Link names to desired locations
3. Save Job
4. Compile Job
5. Close Job
6. Open Job

Comment: Sorry - no option I know.

Comment: Sounds a little weired to me. I know that link names can be messed up, but afaik that only happens when you move the objects around. In general, the design doesn't change "by itself", so to say. Can it by chance be that you're opening the job on a different screen resoluution or sth. like that?